Calculation of amplifying stages on bipolar transistors
please help me. i don`t understand how to do it
To develop a circuit diagram of an AC amplifier on a bipolar
transistor and calculate the values of the nominal elements of the developed
transistor amplifier.
To calculate the circuit, choose a serial bipolar transistor
of a given conductivity type that meets the specified parameters for calculation, and
provide its main data sheet characteristics to confirm the correctness of the
to confirm the correctness of the choice. The values of resistors and capacitors are selected from standard
series.

Power supply voltage: 21 В
Minimum input impedance: 70 kΩ
Load resistance: 4.9 kΩ
Current gain : 14
Lower cutoff frequency: 210 Hz
Input capacitance of the capacitor: 0.155 µF
Output capacitance of the capacitor: 0.155 µF

2N2222 NPN transistor
determine Biasing Resistors (R1 and R2):

Assume:
Vcc = 21 V
Vb (base voltage) = Vc (collector voltage) = 10.5 V (midpoint for biasing)
Vbe = 0.7 V (base-emitter voltage)
Vb = Vcc * (R2 / (R1 + R2))
10.5 = 21 * (R2 / (R1 + R2))
R1 = R2

Ib = Ic / hFE = Ic / 14
V_R1 = Vcc - Vb = 21 - 10.5 = 10.5 V
V_R2 = Vb - Vbe = 10.5 - 0.7 = 9.8 V
Choose R2 such that I_R2 = I_R1
R1 = R2 = V_R1 / Ib

Assume R1 = 330 kΩ and R2 = 180 kΩ (adjusted for standard values)

determine Ic
Ic = Vcc / (Rc + RL)
Assume Vce = 10.5 V (for class A operation)
Rc = (Vcc - Vce) / Ic
Choose Rc = 3.3 kΩ (close to calculated value)
verify Input Impedance (Zin)
Zin = R1 || (R2 + (hFE * (Rc || RL)))
Ensure Zin >= 70 kΩ
With R1 = 330 kΩ and R2 = 180 kΩ, Zin meets the requirement.
calculate Lower Cutoff Frequency (f_L):
f_L = 1 / (2 * π * R_in * C1)
R_in >= 70 kΩ, C1 = 0.155 µF
f_L >= 210 Hz
output Cutoff Frequency
f_L = 1 / (2 * π * RL * C2)
RL = 4.9 kΩ, C2 = 0.155 µF
f_L >= 210 Hz
select Capacitor Values:
C1 = C2 = 0.155 µF (as specified)

For questions like this, which look like homework, to help you we need to now what you have tried and where you are stuck.

AC-31 Артур Козиряцький - Hi, I have made a rough edit to the newly-added text, to add line breaks - otherwise it was very difficult to read/interpret. Some parts are still unclear - my edit didn't/can't fix that, so it's only a partial help. || You seem to have added what looks like some AI / ChatGPT advice about how to solve the original task. But I don't see a schematic. Also I don't see a specific question from you. What's going on? What question are you asking? What prompt did you give to ChatGPT etc.? Note that we don't accept questions which ask us to check genAI/ChatGPT output.

AC-31 Артур Козиряцький - I guess that all of the original question between the line which starts: "To develop a circuit diagram of an AC amplifier" and ending with the line "Output capacitance of the capacitor: 0.155 µF" is the task you were given to do. Is that correct?

I read: Current gain=14 ? Typing error?
